# Good way to encrypt data in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, security

I am working on a fleet management system in PHP. My location tracking is GPS (SMS based): I receive an SMS that contains coordinates (Lat,Lng).

What I want is to encrypt those coordinates. When it comes to database it should be encrypted and when my web application wants it it should convert (decrypt) to its original form. I want to protect the coordinates from illegal access.

Now, how and where should I do encryption and decryption of that data? I need your opinions - I searched a lot but didn't get success.

Comment: Encryption is all about preventing some party access to data it shouldn't have access to. What's your attack scenario you're worried about, whom are you trying to hide data from specifically?

Comment: Hackers who can steal my clients coordinates and can paste them in google map and will get the location easily

Comment: Hackers who can steal your coordinates can probably also hack into your web server and get the necessary code to decrypt the data. In fact, that's likely how they'll get the data in the first place.

Comment: Simply they will get the coordinates from the database and can find the location .its a big privacy risk.  I want to encrypt the coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be no point in encrypting these coordinates - anyone who has access to your database e.g. a database administrator will probably also have access to the decryption key on the web server (assuming you are thinking of using symmetric encryption). Thus, you should work out what kind of threat you are trying to protect against, and then see if your approach would do that.

If you are worried about hackers, the same rules apply as a rogue employee: a hacker who can steal a copy of your database may well be able to steal files off the web server.

If your location data does not need to be decrypted often, or if someone must enter a password to see it, that might be more achievable. You can encrypt the coordinates with a public key, and then only decrypt them with a password-protected private key. An attacker who gets hold of the public key will not be able to use it to decrypt.

It's worth considering also whether this data is so valuable and private that it is worth encrypting at all: you could invest the money you would spend on this project on a third-party security audit of your code instead.

Finally, if this data is regarded as private for data protection reasons, consider fuzzing the data (i.e. introducing small levels of random inaccuracy) rather than encrypting it. This is only an option if you don't need exact coordinates of your vehicles. This is a data protection technique used anonymise data in health trials, where exact location data creates a privacy risk. Of course exact location data is useful for vehicle tracking in the event of theft, so you need to decide what your priorities are here.

---

Further reading: you might be interested in a book called [Translucent Databases](http://www.wayner.org/node/46), which considers encryption, hashing and fuzzing in the context of building data-protected database systems. It's a very thought-provoking read.

Comment: Thanks, Its a great answer @halfer 
My data is the coordinates , which i want to be encrypted Now its a privacy risk, hacker can steal my clients latest coordinates and then will find the exact location . I want a solution that the coordinates should encrypt and when my application wants that coordinates it should come to the application in its original form without requiring any kind of password.
if its possible then its kind of "Easy to use" application, otherwise if its not possible then your idea is far better .

Comment: OK, yes, if the coordinates are transmitted every X minutes, and you want to apply privacy principles to that location data, I'd say that was a good idea. Here in the UK, fleet drivers probably have to agree to relinquish that privacy, which I would not be comfortable with, though some would argue we've given up that civil right via our mobile-phone privacy leakages anyway. Would fuzzing the data be OK? If so, do it at the car end, otherwise the SMS channel becomes another leakage point.

Comment: That of course depends on whether you'd want to use the coordinate stream as a tracker device in the event of theft. If so, the ideal would be to encrypt on the vehicle using a public key, so accurate coordinate data can be obtained only by authorised persons at the server end.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion that I would give is to get a HSM (Hardware Security Module) - something like [YubiHSM](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubihsm/) and install it on a single server. Build an API around it to encrypt and decrypt the data.

Then, there are no keys to steal. For an attacker to decrypt the data, they would need to steal that HSM. The data is useless without the physical chip (which can't be copied).

Comment: Presumably the weakness of this is that if a cracker were to gain access to the web server, they could download the database, and then use the server scripts _in situ_ to decode items on demand, until they were detected and kicked out?

Comment: @halfer only if they could get code onto the network. And if they can do that, they can do far more damage than just decrypting this particular set of information. So I'd assume that all-is-lost *anyway* if they get that far.

Answer (score 0):

For full security they should be encrypted befor they are send via SMS. That way nobody could try to get the SMS and read the cords in it. Second to that you could check if the encrption is done right to ensure that the data you get via SMS are valide. All of this could be done with encryption keys. But those need to be know to the sender and the resiver.

It's possible to encrypt when the data is stored in the DB aswell. But with that all the way to the DB is unsecure and could be used for attacks.

My bigest consurne would be that either someone catches the SMS that's not suposed to read it or even wore that someone sends a corrupted SMS with false data or an injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mcrypt_encrypt` function before entering coordinates in DB and use `mcrypt_decrypt` to decrypt them after retrieving from DB.

Comment: I wouldn't trust most developers to implement this safely. http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2009/7/22/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing.html